# Filter "Last Activity Field" by Task Subject / MapAnything

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula

I'm using MapAnything with Salesforce and would like to color code all of my Sales Representatives' accounts based on how long it has been since they have last visited the account.  This would be easy to achieve using the "Last Activity Field" if I was able to filter this field by activity type.  Currently, we send emails to our customers, and these count as activities; I only want "Visits" to be considered in the formula.  Any ideas?